# is there an IIS equivalent for Android OS

Tags: android, iis

ate present I host my local web site on a windows PC using IIS.  I only serve my pages to my local network.

Is there something similar to IIS in the Android OS?

In essence, I wish to serve HTML5 pages from my Android OS. Using Java is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something similar to IIS in the Android OS?

No.

Moreover, this is not really a programming question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I should have added more detail to my question.  Will do so after my comment.  Is there a way to serve HTML5 pages via an Android OS using Java?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: "Is there a way to serve HTML5 pages via an Android OS using Java?" -- there are Web server apps IIRC on the Play Store. Also, there are libraries that implement an embeddable Web server, for which you can write servlet-style handlers -- see koush's [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync), for example. However, this isn't a big area for Android, just because most people should not be running Web servers on their phones or tablets, except with *great* care, to prevent accidental security issues. Android is not a server OS.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson: In [the book you mentioned](https://commonsware.com/Android), I cover embedding a Web server using AndroidAsync... but only for debug builds, as a way of exposing diagnostic information without mucking up an app's existing UI.

Comment: Hi,thanks for that. I have purchased 1 of those stick USB android devices with the TV Box set. I was not going to use a static IP address. I just wanted to host a couple of html5 pages with the canvas control.  There must be a way to do that  I would have thought?

Comment: Cool.  I shall be doing the purchase later today. You obviously know your stuff so it will be a good for me to upgrade my skills. So, my question has given me a good result regardless :)